# Using sass with html file

Tags: html, css, sass

Today I came to know about sass. So I came through its documentation and installed its package like Ruby and haml on my ubuntu system. Now I want to know that how to use it with Wordpress or any simple html file. As I am totally newbie for this I dont have any idea. Can some one share me any example or link which will help me in learning sass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [follow the tutorial from the SASS website](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html) you will get a CSS file.

Upload that to your server just like any other CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

For Wordpress there's ...

- Sass for WordPress (just Sass): http://thesassway.com/projects/sass-for-wordpress
- Forge (Sass + CoffeeScript): http://thesassway.com/projects/forge
- WordLess (Haml, Sass, CoffeeScript): https://github.com/welaika/wordless

You can also run Sass locally and ship the CSS as you would any project for flat HTML files.